# Windows CMD.exe inserting new line after program runs

Tags: windows, terminal, cmd.exe, newlines

Does CMD.exe automatically put a new line on the terminal window after a program has run? My program is outputing one line of text, via .NET `Console.WriteLine("TEXT");` However, I'm also seeing a blank line when when I run it in CMD.exe. Why is that?

It would look like this:

```
TEXT

C:\>
```

Notice the blank line in the above output. My program only writes 1 line though.

Comment: I think so. It separates it from the text that shows about Microsoft when you open cmd. They might of put it before C :\> rather than after their copyright info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CMD prompt such as `C:\>` is always displayed at the beginning of a line. In order for CMD to be able to guarantee that, it must insert a newline after a console program ends, since the program itself might have left a line not terminated with a newline at the end.

Hypothetically, if CMD did *not* automatically insert a newline after the program ended, and if your code used `Console.Write("TEXT")` instead of `WriteLine`, then the prompt would have ended up being displayed in the middle of the line like `TEXTC:\>`.

Comment: Just a small correction - it inserts **2** newlines. With a bit of trickery you can suppress 1 of them, try `<nul (set/p _any_variable=string to emit)` for example and you will see the blank line is not emitted.

Comment: @DavidPostill As far as I can tell, CMD itself inserts just **1** newline. Most programs end the output with a newline of their own, which makes an extra empty line appear, but that newline is written by the program itself, not CMD. For example, running a console app which does just a `WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), L"test", ...)` with no terminating newline will display `test` on one line then the prompt will appear on the very next line.

Comment: OK, fair enough ...